# Attach a trigger to 'sys.dm_db_missing_index_details'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, trigger

I am trying to attach a trigger to the sys table `sys.dm_db_missing_index_details` with the following query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER indexBackup
ON  sys.dm_db_missing_index_details 
AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for trigger here
EXEC PerformanceTest.[dbo].[usp_persist_missing_index_DMV_data]

END
GO
```

I am getting the following error:

> The object `sys.dm_db_missing_index_details` does not exist or is invalid for this operation.

Is it allowed to attach a trigger to a sys view or am i missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No triggers on system DMVs, sorry.

Besides, you wouldn't really want to do this: that DMV is updated every time a query is run with a missing index request. That could be hundreds or thousands of times per second - and performance matters there.

Instead, consider running an Agent job every 5-15 minutes to capture the data you're looking for.